# Why does List interface extend Collection interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, collections, interface

The Collection interface has multiple methods. The List interface extends the Collection interface. It declares the same methods as the Collection interface? Why is this so?

For example

```
interface Collection extends Iterable
{
     public abstract int size();
 public abstract boolean isEmpty();
 public abstract boolean contains(java.lang.Object);
 public abstract java.util.Iterator<E> iterator();
 public abstract java.lang.Object[] toArray();
 public abstract <T extends java/lang/Object> T[] toArray(T[]);
 public abstract boolean add(E);
 public abstract boolean remove(java.lang.Object);
 public abstract boolean containsAll(java.util.Collection<?>);
 public abstract boolean addAll(java.util.Collection<? extends E>);
 public abstract boolean removeAll(java.util.Collection<?>);
 public abstract boolean retainAll(java.util.Collection<?>);
 public abstract void clear();
 public abstract boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
 public abstract int hashCode();
}
```

and same methods are also present in List interface:

```
public interface List extends Collection
{
 public abstract int size();
 public abstract boolean isEmpty();
 public abstract boolean contains(java.lang.Object);
 public abstract java.util.Iterator<E> iterator();
 public abstract java.lang.Object[] toArray();
 public abstract <T extends java/lang/Object> T[] toArray(T[]);
 public abstract boolean add(E);
 public abstract boolean remove(java.lang.Object);
 public abstract boolean containsAll(java.util.Collection<?>);
 public abstract boolean addAll(java.util.Collection<? extends E>);
 public abstract boolean removeAll(java.util.Collection<?>);
 public abstract boolean retainAll(java.util.Collection<?>);
 public abstract void clear();
 public abstract boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
 public abstract int hashCode();
}
```

Is it a requirement to write these methods again in List if it is already extending the Collection interface?

Comment: I guess just to ensure readability.

Comment: Where did you see that?

Comment: Where are you reading this from? Did you disassemble a `.class` file somewhere?

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-T (open type) "List", in Eclipse. You should know how to find your way (very fast) to the source of any type you use..

Comment: I think that your title is misleading. It asks why does List extend the Collection. But, question is different if fact. As result, many answers answer the title rather than what actually asked. Noise gives raise to more noise. Thanks for doing that.

Answer (score 30):

They're re-written so that they can be documented, in order to specify how the List refines the contract of these methods compared to the contract specified in the Collection interface.

For example, the `add()` method in `List` is documented to specify that the element is added to the end of the list. This can't be specified in Collection, since a Collection doesn't have a beginning and an end.

Comment: Good answer, especially with the example of the `List.add()` contract.

Answer (score 14):

JavaDoc and API contracts change somewhat/ or become more specific, as you move down the inheritance heirarchy.

List re-declares these methods & gives them more specific JavaDoc.

Comment: This probably isn't what the OP meant; he's looking at a disassembly (note the `java/lang/Object` signature), but it's being composited by whatever tool he's using.

Comment: well but my question is List should only contain those methods whose implementation has changed or have some different behaviour here it has written all the method of Collection then what is use of Collection?

Comment: If you want to re-document the methods, or change/ narrow/ further specifify their written & JavaDoc contract, you have to re-declare them. So there's a method signature to attach the JavaDoc to.

Comment: As @JB_Nizet says, `add()` in `List` adds to the end of the List. Collection isn't ordered, so can't make that specification.

Comment: But here you can see we are violating the rule of inheritance that same method we are writing again in List also then what is the use to extending collection inside the List.

Comment: It's legal within the Java language specification, improves correctness by accurately specifying the more-specific _contract_ those methods will fulfill, and breaks no rules that I, the Java compiler or famed collections developer Josh Bloch can see.  _Inheritance is not just about method signatures, but about the overall contract._

Comment: @user2602839 What you're looking at is an internal system representation of the compiled class, not the actual source code of the interface, so don't draw conclusions from the repetition of superinterface methods; it happened automatically.

Comment: @user2602839 that rule is about duplicating the implementation, both List and Collection only declare the methods and do not provide an implementation.

Answer (score 6):

**Just for convenience.**

[Same mentioned in Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

> The List interface places additional stipulations, beyond those specified in the Collection interface, on the contracts of the iterator, add, remove, equals, and hashCode methods. Declarations for other inherited methods are also included here for convenience

Answer (score 3):

`Collection<T>` is just a group of item.
In itself it doesn't have any more requirements than holding references to the many items that are its members.

In the basic java api there is two main types of collections: `List<T>` and `Set<T>`.

`List<T>` have the extra requirement to maintain a certain order (insertion order, sorted order, ...) for all its items. So that if you request item N the list will always return the same item for N.

`Set<T>` does not offer any guarantee on order but offers guarantee on uniqueness of the items. An item A cannot be added twice to a Set, or will appear only once in a set.

You should acquaint yourself with the practice of "marker" interface. `Serializable` is one of those, and generally the basic example when talking about this. And `List<T>` and `Set<T>` are declared as such, they mark a collection as one or the other in order to inform the programmer of the behaviour they can expect from the collection they receive.

Please refer to Item 37 (Chapter  6) of "Effective Java" for a very good explanation on how this is better than using annotations.

And there is also the fact that `myCollection instanceof MyInterface` is faster than `myCollection.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)` or `myCollection.getClass().getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class) != null`.

Answer (score 2):

The signatures on the `toArray` methods suggest that you extracted this from the compiled `.class` files.  The [class file format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html) specifies that the `.class` file does not repeat methods inherited from superinterfaces, so I suspect that whatever tool you used to obtain these was showing you a composite view; the methods aren't actually physically present on `List`.

Comment: Yes, you're correct - the `abstract` modifiers do suggest he's viewing from decompiled class files. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 2):

A collection is just a *collection* of items.

A list, apart from holding list of items, adds information regarding sequence of 
stuff to it.

When you add an item to collection, you are just adding it.
When you add an item to List, you can add at position *n*

When you remove an item from collection, you are just removing it.
When you remove an item from List, you can remove at position *n*

When you want to get an item from collection, you have to iterate.
When you want to get an item from List, you can get at position *n*

Comment: sir well we are doing all those stuff that you have written inside the class that is implementing List interface and Collection interface  but in case of Interface only if we are extending then we will not write the same mathod declaratioin again because for reusablity  we are extending the collection interface inside the List interface

Comment: @user2602839 What am trying to say is, by re-declaring those methods again in `List`, more specific behavior is brought out..

Comment: which type of behavior if you will see the add method then it has written like"public abstratct boolean add(E)" same method have again written inside the List as well as inside the collection also here we are violating the rule of inheritance or not?

Answer (score 1):

First of all interface List inherit all Collection methods,so all methods that exists in Collection interface will exists also in List interface,but List interface have extra methods,(check it by ur self) which describes the behavior of list

Answer (score 1):

It is mainly because of documentation purpose they have used like that.

For example

```
Collection#retainAll
```

Retains only the elements in this **collection** that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation).

```
List#retainAll
```

Retains only the elements in this **list** that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation).

Only for java doc purpose they have used like that. But some of the methods behaviour itself changed.

```
For ex.add,remove
```

**Method remove**

```
In List, Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present (optional operation).

In Collection , Removes a single instance of the specified element from this collection, if it is present (optional operation).
```

Through Java doc they have clearly indicate List implementations are ordered.